# Names vs anonymous functions in TypeScript

Tags: performance, typescript, game-loop

Which one is better in terms of **performance and performance only**?

1)

```
function GameLoop()
{
    // Some heavy calculations
    requestAnimationFrame(GameLoop);     
}
requestAnimationFrame(GameLoop);
```

2)

```
function GameLoop()
{
    // Some heavy calculations
    requestAnimationFrame(function()
    {
       GameLoop();
    });
}
requestAnimationFrame(GameLoop);
```

Comment: have you tested it? what kind of results did you get?

Comment: Both are the **same** in terms of functionality but I need to know how different these two perform regarding efficiency.

Comment: [Rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) ;-) Well, why don't you test it?

Comment: @s952163 and thus I've tested it and here are some interesting results: The second method is better according to basarat's answer but as I've tested it it seems like second one stresses garbage collection more than the first one. Profiling second one creates a sawtooth-styled curve in chrome's dev tools but the first one's curve is less acute. Basically, it takes more time for "garbage" to accumulate in the First one even though the amount of accumulated "garbage" in both situations remains the same. Now I'm more confused...

Comment: Very interesting indeed. My experience with performance is that in many cases the bottleneck is very unintuitive and that measurement is very important. Correct measurement even more so. I think you should be able to answer your own question now by including your findings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> performance and performance only

**1**

Because in `2` you are creating a new function on each iteration.

**More** : in modern vm's they will realize the 2 is creating a same function again and again and will get optimised so the long term performance impact will be minimal.